# Particle filter with error states

Tags: navigation, particle-filter

I am new to particle filters and I have a particle filter based on this:

$$x_{k+1} = f_{k}(x_{k},\omega_{k})$$
$$y_{k+1} = h_{k}(x_{k},v_{k})$$
$$x = [\delta \phi, \delta \theta, \delta \psi, \delta v_n, \delta v_e, \delta v_d, \delta L, \delta \lambda, \delta h, \delta b_{ax}, \delta b_{ay}, \delta b_{az}, \delta b_{gx}, \delta b_{gy},\delta b_{gz}] $$
$$\tilde x = [\tilde \phi, \tilde \theta, \tilde \psi, \tilde v_n, \tilde v_e, \tilde v_d, \tilde L, \tilde \lambda, \tilde h, \tilde f_{x}, \tilde f_{y}, \tilde f_{z},\tilde w_{x}, \tilde w_{y}, \tilde w_{z}] $$
$$ \delta x = \tilde x - x$$
Where:

$\tilde x$ is the indicated parameter and $x$ is the true parameter.

$x$ = the state being from left to right, the errors in roll, pitch, yaw, velocity north, velocity east, velocity down, latitude, longitude, altitude, accelerometer bias body frame x y z, gyro bias body frame x y z.

$\tilde x$ = the parameters, from left to right, the roll, pitch, yaw, velocity north, velocity east, velocity down, latitude, longitude, altitude, accelerometer reading of specific force in body frame x y z, gyroscope reading of angular velocity in body frame x y z.

$k$ = the time index

$\omega_{k}$ is the process noise (zero mean, white noise with known pdf)

$y_k$ is the measurement

$v_k$ is the measurement noise (zero mean, white noise with known pdf).

The functions $f_k(.)$ and $h_k ( . )$ are
time-varying nonlinear system and measurement equations. The noise sequences
$\omega_k$ and $v_k$ are assumed to be independent and white with known pdf’s.

For example, take the latitude error model:
$$ \dot \delta L =  \frac {\delta V_n} {(\tilde R_e + \tilde h)} - \frac { \tilde V_n} {(\tilde R_e + \tilde  h)}^2 \delta h$$
and the height parameter:
$$ \tilde h_{k} = \tilde  h_{k-1} - \frac {t}{2}(\tilde  v_{d(k)}+ \tilde  v_{d(k-1)}) $$
Where $t$ is the discrete time interval between predictions and $\tilde R_e$ is a function of $\tilde L$ and $\tilde h$.

Questions:

1. How do the steps of the particle filter change when the state is an error state?
2. Do the particles change the parameters and if so how and when?
3. Do I have a set of parameters for each particle or one set of parameters which are separate to the particles?
4. Should I predict my parameters forwards or my parameters minus
   particles forwards?
5. Do I ever minus the weighted mean of the particles from the particles for each state except bias?
6. When predicting the velocity parameter forwards, this requires the use of the accelerometer's specific force. it is a good idea to minus the bias first? If so, do I use the weighted mean of the accelerometer bias state of the particles?
7. Do I use the model to predict the parameters and then the particles or the other way around?
8. Is this the latitude error model in discrete:
   $$ \delta L_k = \delta L_{k-1} + (\frac {\delta V_n} {(\tilde R_e + \tilde h)} - \frac { \tilde V_n} {(\tilde R_e + \tilde  h)}^2 \delta h)t$$